# Aggregating and differentiating under integral sign

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, economics

Sorry for being so loose and informal about the mathematical objects that I am using. If your answer depends on some "regularity" conditions you can state them, that would be very useful.

I am working with a continuous random variable $w$, which is distributed over the support $[\underline{w},\overline{w}]$ according to the CDF $G(w)$. I have infinite observations of $w$, say a "continuum of mass one" and of a "well-behaved" function $t(w)$. I want to "aggregate" this observations, I am doing that in the following way:

$$T(w)=\int_{\underline{w}}^{\overline{w}}t(w)dG(w)$$

Would this way of aggregating be correct?

Also, let's say I want to compute $\frac{\partial T(w)}{\partial t(w)}$. Would the correct to do this would be to just take the derivative under the integral sign and obtain:

$$\frac{\partial T(w)}{\partial t(w)}=\int_{\underline{w}}^{\overline{w}}1\cdot dG(w)=G(\overline{w})-G(\underline{w})=1-0=1$$

since I have a continuum I somehow expect to obtain marginal impacts of zero, but this is of course not the case.

Comment: Can you provide some context for $\frac{\partial T(w)}{\partial t(w)}$? I cannot figure out what do you mean when you write the derivative of a function wrt to another function.

Comment: @mlc in an optimization problem, I am dealing with the problem of choosing $t(w)$ optimaly, and $T(w)$ appears in one of the arguments.

Comment: @Ramirez: perhaps you want to look at the first variation (from calculus of variations)?

Comment: @mlc that indeed seems useful. I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation, but what would $h$ represent in this context?

Comment: @Ramirez: you do not have to re-derive the functional derivative. You can just solve the Euler–Lagrange equation (think of it as the FOC).

Comment: @mlc Ok so I am optimizing $u(w-t(w),\int_{\underline{w}}^{\overline{w}}t(w)dG(w))$ and obtain $-u_1(w-t(w),\int_{\underline{w}}^{\overline{w}}t(w)dG(w))+u_2(w-t(w),\int_{\underline{w}}^{\overline{w}}t(w)dG(w))=0$. Does that make sense?